# Switch between views with UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I've went back to hello world tutorials trying to do this. I can't seem to figure this out for some reason, and yet it should be so simple.

I want to have a UINavigationBar with a button on the right side. When the user presses this button, it takes them to a second view through the slide-to-the-side animation, and on this new view the navigationbar shows a back button to the previous view.

How can i get this to happen? I can't for the life of me figure it out. Is there a tutorial somewhere which goes over it? I can't find one.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an UINavigationController with an UIViewController as a root. in the UIViewController you should setup the bar right button. you should have something similar to this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                        initWithTitle: @"Next"
                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                        target:self 
                        action:@selector(nextPage:)] 
                        autorelease];
```

when you touch the button the method nextPage: will be called and will execute the push of the new view.

```
-(void)nextPage:(id)sender
{
   UIViewController *secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
   [secondViewController release];
}
```

here is a tutorial in two parts for using an [UINavigationController](http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the official documentation for the UINavigationController(really useful).

Answer (score 0):

On the button action (the selector) use the following message on self.navigationController

```
 pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES
```

EDIT: Create the UINavigationController as follows:

```
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

And then set the right button as required suggested by Sorin in his answer. And use pushViewController:animated: message on self.navigationController as I have already posted in my original answer. Hope it helps. rootViewController is the view controller you want to have pushed as the first view on your navigation stack.

Comment: That solves that problem - thanks. The problem i have left is how do i make a navigationcontroller, and how do i make sure it appears on those views? I have no idea about that.